# Adding elements to a form in a view, after the form is filled out

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a hidden field in my form that would most easily be included in the view.  Here's what I have now:

```
if request.method == 'POST':                                                                                                                                             
    form = Form(request.POST)                                                                                                                             
    if form.is_valid():                                                                                                                                          
        form.name = name                                                                                                                                
        form.save()                                                                                                                                              
        return HttpResponseRedirect('')
```

There are no errors when I submit the form, and the form elements appear in the DB (so the form works).  The element I add (`form.name`) does *not* appear in the DB, however.  Why doesn't this work, and what can I do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the form with `commit=False`, and then update the `instance`:

```
if form.is_valid():                                                                                                                                          
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.name = 'name'
    instance.save()                                                                                                                                   
    form.save_m2m() # required if there are many-to-many fields in the form
    return HttpResponseRedirect('')
```

See the docs on [the ModelForm save() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) for more info.